# Is ambassador a licensed service? What should be preferred more - Envoy proxy or ambassador?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, microservices, envoyproxy, ambassador

I would like to use a API gateway for a project but I'm bit confused, I'm working in a company where they would like to have envoy proxy as a gateway, 
but as I learned about ambassador I am thinking that ambassador would be better than envoy proxy as it's built on envoy proxy moreover it has consul integrated which acts as a service mesh and Ambassador is built mainly for cloud native applications.

After talking to a senior, he told me that ambassador is a licensed service whereas envoy proxy is free(can be made by ourselves).
Will there be any problem with ambassador because it is licensed?

Moreover, In my opinion, deploying ambassador is easy as compared to deploying envoy proxy.

So it all boils down to:

- What are the main key differences between ambassador and envoy proxy?
- What should be preferred if we want to deploy the microservices on kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambassador Is open source software just like Envoy.

[It's licensed under Apache-2.0](https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/blob/master/LICENSE).
It just so happens that this is the [same license used by Envoy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/LICENSE).

Ambassador does have a PRO version you can pay for to get a few more features.

> Ambassador is a specialized control plane for Envoy Proxy.

So yes, they can do a lot of the same things, but with ambassador on a higher level of abstraction you'll get more value out of it more quickly IMHO. Even if you don't pay for their PRO version.

Envoy is like a lego brick, ambassador is like a spaceship made of several bricks. Envoy can be deployed on servers. Ambasador is built to be K8S native, and really easy to deploy. I don't know your use case specifically, but if I wanted an API gateway running in Kubernetes I would look at Ambassador over Envoy.

Comment: Does the things that PRO version of ambassador have, doesn't supported by envoy proxy? Why Ambassador have the PRO version if envoy proxy can do the same thing without being paid for that?

Comment: https://www.getambassador.io/features has a list of all the features in the open source and the pro version

Comment: As far as I know, Envoy is just a proxy. Ambassador uses it to build an API gateway.
Istio uses it to build a service mesh.

Comment: I looked into that long ago but even though now I'm not sure if we can have those features with envoy proxy or not and that follows the same question - Why Ambassador have the PRO version if envoy proxy can do the same thing without being paid for that?

Comment: Envoy and Ambassador don't have the same features or even projects goals. if you wan to build your own API gateway with Envoy, i think you will have a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: No doubt, that's true, so ambassador is better than envoy in terms of easy to implement, I suppose. I think then that's the only reason.